# Get excel values from single column python xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I've been trying to parse this excel file which has about 6 rows of junk, then header of three columns, followed by all values within each column. I want to graph these using matplotlib but I first need to append all the values to a list. This is what I have so far. I was thinking to just append all values from individual columns, but i cant seem to find a xlrd method that allows me to do that. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
`import xlrd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

file_location = 'C:\Users\jamai_000\samplewaterdata719.xlsx'
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
first_sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for row in range(first_sheet.row):
    print first_sheet.cell_value(row, 0)
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey this can easily be solved using pandas.read_excel:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel("test_import_file.xls",sheetname=0,skiprows=6)
```

Function arguments in the above example:

1. "test_import_file.xls" : path-to-file
2. sheetname = 0: You can select the desired sheet by index with integers or by name with strings
3. skiprows = 6: Skip the first 6 rows of junk.

Ultimately this will read all of your columns into a pandas dataframe which then can be easily integrated with matplotlib.